# Error by running an ansible-playbook with localhost

Tags: ansible, intershop

I use a VM and *Intershop 7.8* to run an *ansible-playbook* (using [this tutorial](https://github.com/IntershopCommunicationsAG/ci-setup-ansible-playbook) ). After installing *Ansible*, copying the content of the repository and configuring it (as shown in the *"quick installation guide"*), I tried to run the ansible-playbook *"setupci.yml"* using the command `ansible-playbook setupci.yml`. Testing this the first time the error `provided hosts list is empty, only localhost available` occurred. Solving this by creating a *"hosts.yml"* file, in which I declared a hostname and using other commands to run the playbook, two new errors occurred.

I tried the following command in the `ci-set-ansible-playbook` directory:

```
$ --limit @[…]/ci-setup-ansible-playbook/setupci
```

I also tried:

```
$ ansible-playbook setupci.yml –connection=local
```

But both caused the errors:

> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {“changed”: false, “connection”: “close”, “content”: “\n \n 404 – Not Found
>
> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {“failed”: true, “msg”: “the field ‘args’ has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined.

Comment: Which version of ansible are u running?

Comment: the first command is obviously incomplete. For the second, add `-vvv`, then show us the Ansible command that is being run when that 404 occurs.

Comment: @WillemEvertse : I run ansible version: 2.3.1.0

Comment: @tedder42 : **When I add -vvv I get the following error**
fatal[127.0.0.1]:FAILED! => { "failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was 'nexus_ishrepo_url' is undefined\n\n The error appears to have been in '/home/intershop1/developer_home/ci-setup-ansible-playbook/roles/nexus/tasks/nexus.yml': line 49,column 3          

**Error 404 occurs:**          
$ anible-playbook setupci.yml --connection=local --limit @/home/intershop1/developer_home/ci-setup-ansible-playbook/setupci.retry

Comment: Edit your question, include that text (formatted) and include the play found in the listed file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess ansible can't load the host vars for your host because the hostname that u defined in hosts.yml doesn't match the file name in /etc/ansible/host_vars/ directory. Maybe you didn't rename the sample.yml file, it needs to match the hostname.

See
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html

[Update]

I tried out this ansible playbook on a docker centos 7 image. I also have some problem with getting it running correctly. However, i do get a connection. Make sure u copy the content of the git repo to /etc/ansible

```
/etc/ansible
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  9191 Sep  7 12:22 LICENSE.md
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  5672 Sep  7 12:22 README.asciidoc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   555 Sep  7 12:22 Vagrantfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 18066 Jun  1 21:49 ansible.cfg
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    42 Sep  7 12:26 group_vars
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  1050 Sep  7 12:31 hosts
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    97 Sep  7 12:22 ishsystem.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  9191 Sep  7 12:22 license-2.0.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root root  4096 Sep  7 12:22 roles
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   138 Sep  7 12:39 setupci.ym
```

edit the hosts file

```
##content of hosts
ciserver ansible_connection=local
```

Check that ansible can connect to the host

```
ansible all -m ping
ciserver | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

copy the sample.yml in group_var to ciserver.yml (same name as in hosts) file and edit it.

```
/etc/ansible/group_vars 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1882 Sep  7 12:26 ciserver.yml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1873 Sep  7 12:22 sample.yml
```

Run the playbook

```
ansible-playbook setupci.yml
```

My scripts stops when it tried to start/stop the firewall. The service doesn't exist on centos so it fails. See if u can get this far.

```
fatal: [ciserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Could not find the requested service firewalld.service: host"}
```

Comment: I have changed it as you said, now the hostname in the host.yml and the file in /etc/ansible/host_vars/ have the same name but it still returns the same error.

Comment: @jri and you did set the repo url with user and password?

Comment: I have added these information, but when I run the ansible playbook, the error still occurs and a sample.yml is created by the system but my renamed sample.yml is still there with the correct name

Comment: Could you make me a step-by-step guide how you have installed it? I think the error that I'm dealing with occurred in some previous steps and couldn't be fixed so easy. I would start it over by using step-by-step guide, so you could help me better when I make the same steps as you did.